# Moving file based on their names

Tags: bash, linux

I have a list of vcf files; I also have a list of names in a txt file like

```
LP6005409-DNA_F01
LP2000325-DNA_A01
LP6005409-DNA_E02
LP6005500-DNA_C03
```

What I have in this txt files are part of name of each vcf files

I want to move .vcf files having these in their name to a separate folder

I done

```
[fi1d18@cyan01 TRG]$ for i in *.vcf
> do if grep -q $i 1.txt;
> cp *$out* /temp/hgig/fi1d18/TRG45/snp/snp/TRG/pre/
> done
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
[fi1d18@cyan01 TRG]$
```

How I can complete this task?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you are getting an error because you are missing a `then` in the third line of your code and then a `fi` to close the `if`. It should be:

```
for i in *.vcf
do if grep -q $i 1.txt; then
    cp *$out* /temp/hgig/fi1d18/TRG45/snp/snp/TRG/pre/
fi
done
```

And I guess the one-liner below achieves what you are trying to do:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do mv "$line"*.vcf some-directory; done < file-list.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

`for i in $(cat text.txt); do cp -v *${i}*vcf mydir; done`